# Connect Qt DoubleSpinBox to PyQGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, qt-designer

I have done a python script and I want to change the '1.0' value on pas15 with the value that is set in the double spin box, but I can't find the way to do it.
Any idea?

```
self.dlg.doubleSpinBox.valueChanged[str].connect(self.value)  

def value(self):
    self.value=QDoubleSpinBox.getValue()  
pas15=processing.runalg('saga:contourlinesfromgrid',self.input,0.0,5000.0,1.0,None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing classes, instances and method names.

- When you get the value, which QDoubleSpinBox should it be retrieved from? Don't specify the class name `QDoubleSpinBox`, specify the instance `self.dlg.doubleSpinBox`.
- When you code, make sure you have the Qt API documentation close so you can check method names: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdoublespinbox.html.

---

```
self.dlg.doubleSpinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.onValueChanged)  

def onValueChanged(self):
    self.value=self.dlg.doubleSpinBox.value()
```

You can also make it simpler, because you get the value with the signal

```
def onValueChanged(self, newValue):
    self.value=newValue
```